# AMD APU Drivers for the latest Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

I´ve just built a new PC with an AMD A6 APU with Radeon R5 graphics. Looking at the AMD website there is a driver download which supports Ubuntu up to 15.10.
Will this driver work with Ubuntu 16.04.4LTS?
Thanks

Comment: What you've found is not the answer. I am not sure how many drivers you need and why, but, perhaps, start with just one: https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx.

Comment: I only need one driver; one that works. Using the AMD "Manually Select Your Driver" only shows the "Crimson Edition" drivers. There is no mention of AMDGPU-PRO. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I have found the answer:

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04

Comment: So does it work or not? Do you really need to download a 3rd party driver from AMD, or does one of the ones (open-source or other) in Ubuntu's repos work? How well does it work with the default Ubuntu setup?